Type 'any Shape' cannot conform to 'Shape'
I am trying to create different shapes on a card based on the card type in Swiftui.
import SwiftUI
let shapes: [any Shape] = [Circle(), Rectangle(), Ellipse()]

struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<shapes.count) { index in
                applyStyling(on: shapes[index])
            }
        }
    }
    
    func applyStyling(on shape: some Shape) -> some View {
        shape.fill(.yellow)
    }
}

But I am getting Type 'any Shape' cannot conform to 'Shape' on applyStyling(on: shapes[index]) line
I understand that when using any Shape it loses the type-specific information on the underlined Shape type, but I guess the same is being done in the example from WWDC Embrace Swift generics at 25:20 timestamp

In reality, I wanted to store all the drawable shapes in an array and then based on the shape type which I can pass to the CardView the appropriate Shape will be drawn.
Can someone guide me on how I can achieve this?
PS: I have already tried the AnyShape trick but that trick is too complicated and not very elegant so I believe there has to be a simpler to achieve this or to structure my code in a different way that handles this problem.

Because protocols don’t conform to themselves and SwiftUI requires concrete types for just about everything.

"I wanted to store all the drawable shapes in an array and then based on the shape type which I can pass to the CardView the appropriate Shape will be drawn" sounds like you should have an array of an enum type instead. You can then switch to decide what shape to draw.
